# How to calculate the sum of elements in an array up to a certain index in Java

Tags: java, for-loop, average

I am trying to figure out how to write a loop that will calculate the sum of elements in an array up to the current index. This is for part of a solution for calculating prefix averages.
I have included my method so far (including the pseudo-code I am trying to write).
I would appreciate any help offered!

```
// getAverages method populates the b array with the prefix averages
public void getAverages()                      
{
    // A prefix average is calculated by averaging all the numbers up to your current index.
    // b[i] is the average of a[0]…a[i], for 0 <= i <= n

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
    {
        b[i] = the sum of all a indexes up to i divided by (i + 1)
    }

}
```

Comment: Sum all the values in the array first, then divide the sum per your array length. Of course, this will only work if your array has at least 1 element.

Comment: For example, suppose a[] = {3, 1, 2, 6}, then b[] = {3.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0}, where b[1] = avg(a[1]); b[2]= avg(a[1]+a[2]); b[3] = avg(a[1]+a[2]+a[3]); and b[4] = avg(a[1]+a[2]+a[3]+a[4]).

Comment: Use the idea I gave you: fill the elements in `b[]` with the sum of the current elements first, then start the divisions.

Comment: I'm not looking for an overall average, I think the comment I just posted explains what I need to accomplish a bit better.

Comment: Jimmy has posted an example of my idea (1st and 2nd comments) but using your `b[]`.

Comment: Wow, thanks for repping me down everyone! Guy comes here for a bit of help and this is what he gets. I never flat out asked for the solution, just a bit of guidance which I got from Luiggi. And I worked it out myself, a bit different than Jimmy's but still works none the less.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
double sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    sum+=a[i];
    b[i] =sum/ (i + 1);
}
```

`sum` stores all the sum up to the current index. I hope it solves your problem.

Comment: `sum` must be `double` in order to have a a `double` result.

Comment: -1 - Providing someone with a potted solution to a "learning to program" problem does not help them learn to program.  It is obvious from the Question that this is one of those problems.

Comment: Wow, thanks for repping me down everyone! Guy comes here for a bit of help and this is what he gets. I never flat out asked for the solution, just a bit of guidance which I got from Luiggi. And I worked it out myself, a bit different than Jimmy's but still works none the less.

Comment: dominicvautour :there are people who are here just to downvote questions and answers without giving reason. If people would downvote and give reasons , like @Stephen C in my above answer , it will be of great help for us to learn more from SO.

Comment: I just find it insulting that I would get downvoted so much for trying to get a bit of guidance... Anyways thanks for your help Jimmy!